# Basic AS 3.0 query

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

What is the best way to navigate through an actionscript swf using arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `tabIndex` property of the `TextInput`. That should allow you to tab through the form.

It is inadvisable to override the default functionality for arrow keys because they are used to move the text insertion point within the textInput

As for enter, you'll have to listen for the keyUp event and, if you detect an enter key, move to the next field.

```
//add this eventlistener for each textbox (through a loop or manually)
t.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, k);

//The event handler
protected function k(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER) {
         focusManager.getNextFocusManagerComponent().setFocus();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For Flash CS5, this code should work:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import fl.managers.FocusManager; 
import flash.display.InteractiveObject; 
import fl.managers.IFocusManagerComponent;
import fl.managers.IFocusManager;

t1.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, k);
t1.tabIndex=1;
t2.tabIndex=2;

var fm:FocusManager=new FocusManager(this);

t1.tabEnabled=true;
t2.tabEnabled=true;

function k(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER) {
         var fx:InteractiveObject = fm.getNextFocusManagerComponent();
         fm.setFocus(fx);
    }
}
```

**important:** first drag a component from the "User Interface" group onto the stage and delete it. This should put all the required components in the library ready for you to use

**EDIT2**

Change

```
for(var i:int=0; i < textbox.length; i++) {
        //textbox[i].buttonMode = true;
        //box[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myclick_ftn);
        //box[i].addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN,textInputHandler);
        //box[i].addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT,textInputHandlerOut);
        textbox[i].restrict = "0-9";
        textbox[i].addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, k);
        textbox[i].tabIndex=i;
        //t2.tabIndex=2;

        //textbox[i].tabEnabled=true;

                var fm:FocusManager=new FocusManager(this);


        function k(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER) {
                var fx:InteractiveObject = fm.getNextFocusManagerComponent();
                fm.setFocus(fx);
    }
}
        //t2.tabEnabled=true;
}
```

in your code to this:

```
var fm:FocusManager=new FocusManager(this);


function k(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER) {
        var fx:InteractiveObject = fm.getNextFocusManagerComponent();
        fm.setFocus(fx);
    }
}

for(var i:int=0; i < textbox.length; i++) {
        //textbox[i].buttonMode = true;
        //box[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myclick_ftn);
        //box[i].addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN,textInputHandler);
        //box[i].addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT,textInputHandlerOut);
        textbox[i].restrict = "0-9";
        textbox[i].addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, k);
        textbox[i].tabIndex=i;
        //t2.tabIndex=2;

        //textbox[i].tabEnabled=true; 

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am using textboxs that are set to input, not components so I am having errors with the 40 textboxs. any suggestions?

Comment: your so awesome! one last question I hope, what should t2 be referring to?  and sadly im using CS4 :(

Comment: oh... t1, t2 and so on are the instance names of the text fields you have.. You might want to loop over the array and set `tabEnabled=true` and `tabindex=whatever`

Comment: on second thought, setting `tabEnabled` isn't really required

Comment: I commented out the end of my code...still having problems with the enter.  If you have time could u look at it?  I changed the code in my first post.

Comment: and I changed them all to textInput components :)

Comment: what's wrong now? It doesn't really matter whether they are text fields or TextInput components

Comment: this line:  var fm:FocusManager=new FocusManager(this);  also, just edited the code again

Comment: put that line and the entire function k outside the loop

Comment: I did.  I have two errors 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FocusManager.1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FocusManager.

Comment: yeah the imports are there ill put my new code at the top again after i do this.  in the edit two, the error TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at 1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1  keeps coming up.  I fixed the other two errors .

Comment: add `if(fx) ` before `fm.setFocus(fx);`. That will make it `if(fx) fm.setFocus(fx);`

Comment: got rid of it.  Redid all the combo boxes and restarted flash.   thank you so much! :)

Comment: what do you think the best way is to get the previous focus so that I could compare the items typed to what it should be?

Comment: `fm.getNextFocusManagerComponent(true)` should get you the previous object in the focus queue

Comment: I did that. I am not really sure how to use that to find the last textInput that had text inputted so that I can compare to the actual answer.

Comment: `(fx as TextField).text` will give you the text of the `TextField` that will be focussed by that code I gave you. If you have changed the textFields to textInputs, use `(fx as TextInput).text`